# Transfer array of bytes (gcroot<System::Byte []> cosbuf;) from /oldsyntax to /clr

Tags: c++-cli, managed-c++

I have now updated my c++ project from /oldsyntax to /clr, but I have problems to run it.

The old program (which runs fine has this)

```
gcroot<System::Byte []> cosbuf;  (in header file)
```

And this in the constructor

```
cosbuf = new System::Byte[4096];  // This will not compile
```

and then this in the cpp file

```
System::Byte __pin *cosbuf_pin = &cosbuf[0];
char *cosbuf_ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(cosbuf_pin);
```

I tried to convert it to :

```
gcroot<array<System::Byte>^> cosbuf;  // in .h file

array< System::Byte >^ cosbuf = gcnew array< System::Byte >(4096); // in constructor

pin_ptr<unsigned char> cosbuf_pin = &cosbuf[0];     // in cpp program
char *cosbuf_ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(cosbuf_pin);
```

This compile, but the cosbuf_pin assignement with pin_ptr throw exception with "Object reference not set to an instance of the object".

Either I need other ways of having a cosbuf_ptr to the cosbuf or some other data structures is needed. Basically an array of 4096 bytes is needed for this buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a new variable in the Constructor instead of using the one defined in the class.

Replace

**array< System::Byte >^** cosbuf = gcnew array< System::Byte >(4096); // in constructor

with

cosbuf = gcnew array< System::Byte >(4096); // in constructor

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solved the issue. Now the new c++ dll generated by Visual Studio 2013 works

Comment: But it gives error E0079 (expected a type specifier) and E0442 (C++ too few arguments for class template "std::array")

Comment: Works with : cosbuf = gcnew cli::array< System::Byte >(4096);